# Why doesn't my computer paddle move in my Pong game?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a pong game and I can't figure out why the computerPaddle won't move up or down when it's supposed to to hit the ball automatically!

Please help me.

Here's code:

```
<html>
<h3>- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
PONG- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -</h3>

<canvas id="gameCanvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>

<script>
var canvas;
var canvasContext;
var ballX = 50;
var ballY = 50;
var ballSpeedX = 11;
var ballSpeedY = 5;

var playerPaddleY = 240;
var computerPaddleY = 240;
const paddleHeight = 120;
const paddleThickness = 12;

function calculateMousePos(evt) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    var root = document.documentElement;
    var mouseX = evt.clientX - rect.left - root.scrollLeft;
    var mouseY = evt.clientY - rect.top - root.scrollTop;
    return {
        x: mouseX,
        y: mouseY
    };

}

window.onload = function() {

    canvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
    canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var framesPerSecond = 30;

    setInterval(function() {
        moveEverything();
        drawEverything();
    }, 1000 / framesPerSecond);

    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',
        function(evt) {
            var mousePos = calculateMousePos(evt);
            playerPaddleY = mousePos.y - (paddleHeight / 2);
        });

}

function ballReset() {
    ballX = canvas.width / 2;
    ballY = canvas.height / 2;
    ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX;

}

function computerMovement() {
    if (computerPaddleY < ballY) {
        computerPaddleY += 5;
    } else {
        computerPaddleY -= 5;
    }
}

function moveEverything() {

    ballX += ballSpeedX;
    ballY += ballSpeedY;

    if (ballX > canvas.width) {
        if (ballY > computerPaddleY && ballY < computerPaddleY + paddleHeight) {
            ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX;
        } else {
            ballReset();
        }
    }

    if (ballX < 0) {
        if (ballY > playerPaddleY && ballY < playerPaddleY + paddleHeight) {
            ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX;
        } else {
            ballReset();
        }

    }

    if (ballY > canvas.height) {
        ballSpeedY = -ballSpeedY;
    }

    if (ballY < 0) {
        ballSpeedY = -ballSpeedY;
    }

}

function drawEverything() {

    canvasContext.fillStyle = 'black';
    canvasContext.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    canvasContext.fillStyle = 'white';
    canvasContext.fillRect(2, playerPaddleY, paddleThickness, paddleHeight); // 
    player

    canvasContext.fillRect(786, computerPaddleY, paddleThickness, 120);
    //computer player

    canvasContext.beginPath();
    canvasContext.arc(ballX, ballY, 12, 0, Math.PI * 2, true); //ball
    canvasContext.fill();

}

</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The only code that ever appears to modify `computerPaddleY` is in the `computerMovement` function. You never call `computerMovement` anywhere.

Presumably your intent was to call it during `moveEverything`, but you're currently not.